# Contact Form 7 Custom Post Action

Tags: ajax, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I found this thread here discussing this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177844/how-to-change-form-action-url-for-contact-form-7

However it seems that using the following code does not work as the contact form is submitting with ajax back to CF7 and ignoring the post action.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');
function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url(){
    return 'www.myposthandler.com';
}
```

Is there a way to disable the ajax submission?

Site where this is happening: https://daintreecapital.com.au/ the newsletter subscription form in the footer is what I am trying to alter.

Comment: BTW, don't you need to included the protocol on the return value (for those that are lurking)? As in return 'http://www.example.com/posthandler' ?

Comment: Yes, in use I put the actual handler there I just didn't want to post it on a public forum.

Comment: My point was that the return value should include the "https://" part (which actually doesn't appear in the comment, due to how this place formats links).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [CF7 Documentation](https://contactform7.com/loading-javascript-and-stylesheet-only-when-it-is-necessary/), you can disable AJAX form submission by placing the following code in your `wp-config.php`

```
define('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false);
```

Comment: That disables ALL JS

Comment: @crmpicco It disables Contact Form 7's JS. Is there any other functionality of CF7 that depends on JS?

Comment: @Junaid field validation I guess.

Comment: @Fleuv IMHO, if CF7's JS is disabled, it'll take the input to the server, validate, return to the form and show the errors. So, we are not loosing any validation functionality.

Comment: How do you disable it only for a certain form?

Comment: In my case this doesn't disable AJAX submissions but makes AJAX requests successful without the following API error: "contact-forms/[form_id]/feedback – 404". I'm using Contact Form 7 V5.0.5